# Template-based wrapper function for boost::bimap lookup not correctly working

Tags: c++, boost

I have a pair of functions which, simply put, retrieve the left/right values of a bimap and print a message (or, depending on a bool arg of the function, cause a fatal error in the program):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
template<typename Lt, typename Rt>
Rt Q_bimapleft( boost::bimap<Lt, Rt> themap, Lt L, bool throwError = false )
{
    try
    {
        Rt returnVal = themap.left.at(L);
        return returnVal;
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
        if( throwError )
        {
            Com_Error(ERR_FATAL, "Q_bimapright failure on lookup of %s\n", boost::lexical_cast<char *, Lt>(L));
        }
        else
        {
            Com_Printf(S_COLOR_YELLOW "WARNING: Q_bimapright failure on lookup of %s\n", boost::lexical_cast<char *, Lt>(L));
        }
    }
    return (Rt)-1;
}

template<typename Lt, typename Rt>
Lt Q_bimapright( boost::bimap<Lt, Rt> themap, Rt R, bool throwError = false )
{
    try
    {
        Lt returnVal = themap.right.at(R);
        return returnVal;
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
        if( throwError )
        {
            Com_Error(ERR_FATAL, "Q_bimapleft failure on lookup of %s\n", boost::lexical_cast<char *, Rt>(R));
        }
        else
        {
            Com_Printf(S_COLOR_YELLOW "WARNING: Q_bimapleft failure on lookup of %s\n", boost::lexical_cast<char *, Rt>(R));
        }
    }
    return (Lt)-1;
}
#endif
```

However, when I go to use the function:

```
....
boost::bimap<int, std::string> animTable;
char token[1024];
....
int index = Q_bimapleft<int, std::string>(animTable, token);
```

Intellisense/the compiler reports:

```
IntelliSense: no instance of function template "Q_bimapleft" matches the argument list
```

Comment: What are the argument types?  What is animTable and token.string?

Comment: Updating original post with more information.

Comment: Please include: compiler version, complete compiler error (not intellisense), an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Q_bimapleft<int, std::string>(animTable, token);
```

must have signature as

```
(boost::bimap<int, string> themap, std::string)
```

not

```
(boost::bimap<int, string> themap, int)
```

in other words, you are trying to pass `char*` as `int`